# Density of holes in the valence band?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

In my notes, the number density of holes in a semiconductor is given as:
$$ p(T) = \int_{-\infty }^{E_v}{d\epsilon g_v(\epsilon)\left( 1 - \frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon - \mu)}+1}\right)}$$ 
I am confused about $$\left( 1 - \frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon - \mu)}+1}\right) $$
term. Specifically, why is it not:
 $$ \frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon - \mu)}+1}$$
Why do holes obey a different statistic and not Fermi-Dirac Statistic. In a way, this intuitively makes sense. Hole is an abssence of an electron, so it makes sense to have $ 1- electron \ statistic $ there, but I am looking for a more rigorous way of demonstraiting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the valence band is almost completely filled with electrons. Consequently, the material properties such as the electrical currents comes from the motions of electrons among the remaining vacancies (holes).

Consequently :

Probability to find a hole = 1-probability to find an electron.

That's actually very rigorous and it is a very general approach in statistics.

For example, the probability to get 6 with a dice is 1/6 and the probabilty NOT to get a 6 is 1-1/6=5/6.